# Adding padding around text

Tags: html, css, padding

Why won't this work or apply spacing around my text?

```html
<style>
.headertext
div {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  
}
</style>

<div class= "headertext"><font size="2" color= "#ffffff"><p class="Roboto">PAGE TITLE</p></font></div>
```

Please help :)

Comment: You should delete font tag and tell us where you want the padding.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're looking for padding or margin. Your current CSS should add 20 margin to the left of all divs. If you want padding specifically around the text you could add a CSS rule for the .Roboto class, for example "padding: 20px".

Answer (score 0):

delete `font` tag

```css
.headertext {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headertext">
  <p class="Roboto">PAGE TITLE</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.headertext{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.headertext > p{
   font-size:14px;
   color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="headertext">
    <p>PAGE TITLE</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer with using your html.Click button "Run code snippet" to see output. I have added backgrounds to show padding around text. You can remove newly added colors.

```css
 body{background-color:green;}
.headertext {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px; 
}
p{
   padding:15px;
   background-color:
   blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class= "headertext"><font size="2" color= "#ffffff"><p class="Roboto">PAGE TITLE</p></font></div>
```